# Using diagnose_category in for loop

Tags: r

I am finding it difficult to embed a piece of code inside a function. I would like to create a function that accepts a table and then applies the following to each column of the table:

```
diagnose_category(as.data.frame(My_Table$Some_Var)) %>% arrange(rank) %>% top_n(-2)
```

I tried embedding it in the following for loop but can't figure out what I should change `My_Table$Some_Var` to

```
for(col in names(My_Table)) {
    diagnose_category(as.data.frame(as.data.frame(My_Table$Some_Var))) %>% arrange(rank) %>% top_n(-2)
}
```

What must I change `My_Table$Some_Var` to?

Comment: How about `My_Table[, col]`?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik thik I've been really overthinking this. Need to get used to R. This subsetting is not something I got in my Java classes. Thanks.

Comment: It takes a bit getting used to, but it's really nice, you'll see!